# Why do barriers have a blast resistance of 18,000,003 rather than 18,000,000?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been looking at the [minecraft blast resistance values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_resistance), and I came across something strange:

- Bedrock has a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- Structure blocks have a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- Command Blocks have a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- End Gateway Blocks have a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- End Portals have a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- End Portal Frames have a blast resistance of 18,000,000.
- Barriers have a blast resistance of 18,000,003.

That last one seems kinda odd to me. 18,000,000 is basically indestructable, 18,000,003 is *almost exactly the same*. I really don't see why barriers would be 3 levels harder to destroy than bedrock, structure blocks, command blocks, end gateways, end portals, and end portal frames.

Is there a good reason for this anomaly? If so, what is it?

Comment: There is a dispute on the blast resistance of barriers

according to https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Barrier (official minecraft wiki), it has a blast resistance of 3,600,000.8

However, according to https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Barrier#:~:text=The%20Barrier%20is%20an%20invisible,)%2C%20as%20it%20is%20indestructible. (Fandom wiki), barriers have a blast resistance of 18,000,003, according to you.

So I think there is no definite blast resistance for blocks like bedrock or command blocks, since they are indestructible and don't need to have blast resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like nobody knows. The [edit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Module:Blast_resistance_values&diff=prev&oldid=806127) in the Minecraft wiki just says "corrected barrier, for some reason it is 18,000,003". I don't think it's worth creating a bug report for it, since it has no downside to have this value. It might be a typo.